# How to add a dynamic field to an instance in Java?

Tags: java

We have logic like the following image:

[image]

In our application, we have a DAO layer, this layer is packaged and I don't be allowed to modify it.
We have a booking service, it will call DAO to save our entity to the database. The entity is stored as a JSON string.

Now, I have a situation that I would like to store one more field (for example version field) in JSON content for all entities. How can I do it with Java?

**Note:** Remember that I don't be allowed to change the repository layer or database.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have written convertor of Book entity to convert content(JSON) in your service layer.
If my assumption is right, then you just need to pass the version in JSON from service layer and update the convertor.

I didn't see any blocker around that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @prateek3636. But your answer is not as my expectation. As I said that, I don't be allowed to modify anything in the repository, even the JSON converter.

Comment: Yes, but I am asking about changing the service layer.

Comment: You can see at the repository layer, it receives a DTO (not a JSON string). We can convert it at the service layer, but we can not put it in the repo.

Comment: We also can create a class extend from BookDTO and add version field in that child class, but it's very specified for a Book business, we have many classes like that and sometimes we can not know exactly the Entity business will be put to the repo. This way is not good to do. So, I think it's better if we can add a dynamic field to DTO at the service layer and it will automatically affect to all Entities at the repo layer without adding any new classes.